# Why is ReSharper telling me that "User.Identity == null" will always be false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper

I have a simple property inside one of my ASP.NET MVC [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) classes.

[image]

I've seen this many times before, so understand what the message means, but usually it makes perfect sense. This, however, doesn't. To get to the underlined statement, `User` would have to **NOT** be null, so the check for `User.Identity` is fine.

The `Identity` property is part of the [`IPrincipal` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity.aspx), and returns an object that inherits [`IIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx).

To inherit this interface, or any interface for that matter, this property must be a reference type, and therefore can potentially be null, right?

So why is my beloved ReSharper moaning?

Comment: I think this question needs more context. How is `User` defined? How is it used in the class?

Comment: @WillVousden it's a property on the Controller class. It's part of the ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: I run into many cases like this. I either tell resharper to ignore this special case with special code comments, or I disable the notification completely if it is for something I would care less about. Everything can't be perfect, but I think resharper makes up for these slight issues.

Comment: @WillVousden User is part of the Controller class that I linked to in the first line. It inherits `IPrincipal`.

Comment: @PaulKnopf but those special resharper comments are so damn ugly!! :(

Comment: Maybe it just knows that it is very unlikely that this property is going to be null.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You said you are using the `GenericPrinciple` as the implementation of `IPrincipal`. For this class, the `Identity` property can indeed never be `null`. It is easy to see if you look at the source code (e.g. using [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)).

You can thank ReSharper's code annotations for the .NET framework class libraries for this.

In my ReSharper 6.1 annotations, there is this single code annotation related to this (in file *ExternalAnnotations\mscorlib\mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Nullness.Generated.xml*):

```
  <member name="M:System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal.#ctor(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity,System.String[])">
    <parameter name="identity">
      <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
    </parameter>
  </member>
```

This is just for the constructor though, I haven't found one for the `Identity` property. So either you are using a ReSharper version that has annotation for that property too or ReSharper is doing some additional analysis.

**In any case, it is ReSharper being clever (and right!).**

Comment: You'd think there'd be a [NotNull] attribute at least? And if this is the case, why wouldn't it moan about my check for `User == null` too?

Comment: Because you could obviously set `User = null` somewhere in your own custom controller class before.

Comment: Because `User` actually *can* be `null`.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html  There is a `[NotNull]` attribute.

Comment: I don't think you can actually set the `User` property, but if I could, then I could set it to my own object that inherits `IPrincipal`. This object could have a null value for the `Identity` property.

Comment: @cadrell0, I mean for the `Identity` property.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins That article explains that these annotations are stored in XML files in "ReSharper_installation_dir\Bin\ExternalAnnotations.".  ReSharper cannot modify the .NET Framework to add these.

Comment: @cadrell0, so are you telling me the NotNull attribute **is** in those XML files? That would indeed answer the question.

Comment: @bitbonk, my IPrincipal implementation is the `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal` class ;)

Comment: @cadrell0: +1 (in your comment) for pointing out `ReSharper_installation_dir\Bin\ExternalAnnotations` xml file. I didn't know that this xml existed. =)

Comment: Came back this morning and suddenly, brilliant answer! Explained everything between you and @cadrell0. Thank you both :)